# Will an Android Nearby advertisment trigger any kind of UI on nearby devices?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Following [this article](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started) i discovered a comment stating that

> Advertising with an AppIdentifer lets other devices on the network discover this application and prompt the user to install the application.

How does the second user interact with this solution? Is there any kind of UI, like a notification? Has anybody tried this yet? Is this available only for a specific use case like Android TV devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearby Connections leaves it to you, the developer, to create UX that makes sense for your use-case. There are two sides to the API. The [advertising side](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started) and the [discovering side](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/discover-devices). Nothing happens when you advertise unless another device calls the discovery API and even then, it's up to your app whether or not to display anything.

When a second device invokes [startDiscovery](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections.html) it will get an onEndpointFound callback. That's an opportunity to display UX or call sendConnectionRequest (to establish the connection)

Comment: But what does the comment mean then? For the cases you describe both devices need the app to be installed, such a prompt would be meaningless then.

Comment: Ah! I see where the confusion comes from. We need to update our documentation. Simply advertising with Nearby.Connections will _not_ show a notification. Following up internally to clear up the documentation...